# jQuery detecting if php $_POST isset

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm new to jQuery, and just wondering if there's a way to detect if a form has been submitted on page load, and if so parsing some code.

I have:

```
<form action="/login/register" method="post"> 
    <input type="text" value="Username" name="regName"/>
    <input type="password" value="Password" name="regPass"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Register"/>
</form>
```

and:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['regName']))
{
//check inputs and add account
}

?>
```

But i was wondering if i could check if the form had been submitted via jQuery?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just have PHP set a javascript variable to true if a POST submission was made. Then jQuery just needs to check its value.

```
<script type="text/Javascript">
    var was_posted = <?php echo ('POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>
</script>
```